# Plot Experimental Data Distribution

Tags: java

I'm working on a clustering task and I've built the dataset similarity matrix M, repeating N times the clustering algorithm and chosing as element m_{ij} the the number of times the elements i and j have been on the same cluster, divided by N.

Now I'd like to have a graphical way to check my results, so i was wondering if there is any library that, given an array of doubles ( aka the values in the upper triangular part of my matrix ), plots the data distribution and the histogram ? All the doubles are in the [0,1] interval, and most of the will be around 0 and 1 .

Answer (score 0):

For plotting, the best programming language that I know is `Matlab`. If you have chance, I would definitely suggest you `Matlab`.

Write your results into a txt file and just insert it into Matlab, then you can play with that numbers and do plottings with almost no effort